# Table is not scrollable

Tags: html, css, scrollable

I coded a table and this table has so much information in it that if the page is on 100% more than half of the table is missing.

I hope you can help me. You have to add more of the table cells to recreate it.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  transition: var(--tran-05);
  background-color: #18191a;
  --body-color: #18191a;
  --sidebar-color: #242526;
  --primary-color: #3a3b3c;
  --primary-color-light: #3a3b3c;
  --toggle-color: #fff;
  --text-color: #ccc;
}

table.content {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #201f1b;
}

table.content thead tr {
  background-color: #403f46;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

table.content th,
table.content td {
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

table.content tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table.content tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #403f46;
}

table.content tbody tr.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #403f46;
}
```

```html
<table class="content">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ServerID</th>
      <th>Server Owner</th>
      <th>Premium Server</th>
      <th>Dev Server</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is either about HTML or PHP. It can't really be both. Please show us the rendered output.

Comment: I added them under the Code

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code must not be presented as images. We can't work with that. Please use the editor to create a working demo of your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Now? Like this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of this:

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

it calculates -50% on the y-axis, which results in a cut. This works fine, but not for long elements.
Instead of this, just using a div as a wrapper around the table.
Update your code like the following:

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="content">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ServerID</th>
        <th>Server Owner</th>
        <th>Premium Server</th>
        <th>Dev Server</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
      <td style='color: white'><b>Test</b></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  table.content {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 400px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 2%;
    color: #f9f9f9;
  }
```

now it should work correctly.

Comment: Now the complete Top of the Table is missing

Comment: with your provided code it works perfectly. I've tested it already. I meant, that you need to override your table.content with my table.content.